# Unable to use an environment variable in command prompt, even though I can print it's value using echo command

Tags: python, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

I have declared my environmental variables as follows:

> Ctrl+x -> system -> advanced system settings -> Environment Variables

and there, I have set a new user variable with name **python**

However, when I type **python** in command prompt, i get this error

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

When I use the echo command, it shows me the value of my environment variable, which makes me think that I have done all the steps right. I cannot figure out why am I unable to use my environment variable.

I have attached a snapshot showing my cmd commands[image]

I have done my own research on this, but I can't figure out why, when the echo command works on the variable, am i unable to use it. Have triple checked whether the path exists, and it does. 
Also, the H:\ drive ( referring to the above image ) is an external portable hard drive connected to my pc via usb.

Comment: can you run it from within H:  ???

Comment: This seems more appropriate for superuser.com.

Comment: sorry, i donot know what superuser is

Comment: @mlwn when i give this path explicitly, then it runs, yes.

Comment: why did you install python on your external drive ?? :)

Comment: @mlwn because my c drive has run out of space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a variable, you need to retrieve its value, not use its name. If you use `%python%` to echo its value, use `%python%` to call the executable

Comment: yes, it works now! thanks a lot! Think I need more practice with cmd

Comment: if you append a value to the variable name **path**, then would you still use % symbol? like C:\Windows;H:\Python; I am confused because if the **path** user variable has many paths assigned to it separated by semicolons, then how can you refer to one of them? Actually the tutorial that I am following uses the **path** user variable, and when using it in cmd, doesn't use the % symbol

Comment: @ColorDeColor, yes, or course you can add the folder where your executable is located to the `path` environment variable and then you will not need to use your declared variable. When you call an executable it is searched in the folders listed in the path variable. Remember you have to add the folder (full path) where the executable are stored.